# Deleting elements from numpy array and overwriting the same array with the deleted reference copy which is created after deletion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of dimension `v[0].data - (96,3,11,11)` and after deletion of 20 rows along `axis = 0`, the dimension becomes `a -(76,3,11,11)` which is the copy that is created after deletion
.
What I want here is to modify `v[0].data` to dimension `(76,3,11,11)`.

I have tried `np.copy()` and `np.copyto()` to copy array `a` to `v[0].data` which is not working since the original size is `(96,3,11,11)` and I get dimension mismatch error.

I want to overwrite in the same numpy array i.e. `v[0].data` and make its dimensions `(76,3,11,11)`.

How should I do it?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean. Please provide a (small) example. Perhaps slicing is what you need?

Comment: Actually I want to delete elements from my original numpy array  and want to decrease it size but if I use np.delete operation one more copy is created after deletion. I dont want to use copy of the numpy array.

Comment: What is the problem with creating a copy? The original will be garbage collected if you have no references to it. If you cannot, by any means, allow a copy to be created, you can use slicing and only use a certain part of the original array, but that will be a bit cumbersome, as you need to keep writing `v[0].data[20:,:,:,:,:]` all over the place. And I don't know if you can copy into a slice, using the copy functions either.

Comment: I have my deep network weights saved in this numpy arrray and I want to discard some weights and keep the rest of the weights and save the smaller version of the same weights numpy array in my model that's why I don't want any copy of the array.

Comment: What is `v`? `v[0]`?  Can you do `v[0].data=a`?

Comment: Fixed code formatting.

Comment: @hpaulj  v[0].data is my numpy array. No I cannot assign it like this.

Comment: Is `v[0]` the array, or is `.data` the attribute of some other class of object.  Why can't you assign it?  You can assign new values to an array with `data[...] =a`, but you can't change its size.  You'll need to be more informative; otherwise your question is likely to be closed before you get an answer.